# Selenium just randomly just stalls out and stays on the browser doing nothing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

so I am making a program that reads an excel sheet for name and searches it up on this business directory called Buzz File. It works perfectly just that the selenium just randomly stalls out and does not do anything. When I increase the time in between it works a bit better but still stalls out and just stays on that link forever. Here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_name(input_string):
    output_string = ""
    for char in input_string:
        if char == " ":
            output_string += "-"
        elif char == "&":
            output_string += ".AND."
        else:
            output_string += char
    return output_string

def first_name(name):
    name = str(name).split()
    name = name[0]
    return name

def last_name(name):
    name = str(name).split()
    name = name[-1]
    return name

def get_address(address):
    address = str(address).split()
    address = ' '.join(address[:1])
    return address

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# Use ChromeDriverManager to install/ manage the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

def get_company(the_url, address_number):

    url = "https://www.buzzfile.com/Search/Company/Results?searchTerm={}&type=1".format(the_url)
    driver.get(url)

    addresses = []
    links = []
    iter = 0
    list_number = 0

    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@rel='nofollow' and contains(@href, '/User/SignIn')]"):
        addresses.append(item.text)

    addresses.append("")
    addresses = addresses[10:]
    addresses = addresses[::6]


    for item in addresses: 
        item = str(item).split()
        item = ' '.join(item[:1])
        if item == address_number:
            list_number = iter
            break
        iter += 1

    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@style='color:rgb(24,81,139);']"):
        links.append(item.get_attribute("href"))

    if len(links) == 0:
        return "https://www.buzzfile.com/business/Fullford-Electric,-Inc.-907-456-7356"
    return links[iter]

def get_info(link):
    driver.get(link)
    try:
        company_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@itemprop='employee']"))
        )
        return company_element.text
    except:
        print("Timeout occurred while getting info for:", link)
        return ""

def get_url(link):
    driver.get(link)
    try:
        url_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@style='color:#337ab7;' and @itemprop='url']"))
        )
        return url_element.text
    except:
        print("Timeout occurred while getting URL for:", link)
        return ""



df = pd.read_excel("TestDummy.xlsx")
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company Name', 'Address', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Website'])


i = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    time.sleep(15)
    buzz_url = get_company(row['Company Name'], get_address(row['Address']))
    get_url(buzz_url)
    dict = {'Company Name': [row['Company Name']],
            'Address' : [row['Address']], 
            'First Name':[first_name(get_info(buzz_url))], 
            'Last Name':[last_name(get_info(buzz_url))],
            'Website':[get_url(buzz_url)]}
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['Company Name', 'Address', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Website'])
    new_df = pd.concat([data_df, new_df], ignore_index=True)
    print("ping " + str(i))
    if i == 10:
        driver.quit()
        break
    i += 1

new_df.to_excel("Names-Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please, show us the line where Selenium stacks and provide your excel file just to have minimal reproducible example.